# Unable to connect to Internet after wakeup from hibernate?

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10, system-settings, ifconfig

It says Networking is Disabled. I have tried checking that box (which stays checked); but that does nothing.

Even tried: `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`; which also did nothing. I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 x64.

Comment: Note that after a reboot it works fine again.

Comment: I have the same issue using 14.04 once it hibernates the only thing I have found to get my network operational is a reboot.

Comment: by the way I have enable networking checked and the other option ( "sudo ...")posted.  My machine is hibernating vs sleep mode if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this problem. I have discovered that if you check the "Enable Networking" box, put it to sleep, and then wake it up again, it works. Eventually after doing it for a while the problem seemed to stop.